# Restrict access to a hive page

Tags: 2010, web-config, incoming-email, security-trimming

The purpose is to block the Incoming e-mail settings internal page (/_layouts/EmailSettings.aspx) to non-admin users or, simply, to all with an exception account.

Via [authorization element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in web config no access is restrain with the following entry:

```
  <location path="_layouts/EmailSettings.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
      <deny users="*"/> 
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not recommendable**, but I added the following code to the layout page:

in a script element, with runat="server" property

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.IsSiteAdmin) 
            SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new Exception("Only Site Admins can access Incoming e-mail settings."));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I did exactly this a couple of years back was developing a SharePoint DelegateControl WebControl and staple it to the PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead.

The WebControl would include code to check if the "/_layouts/EmailSettings.aspx" page is hit and if so check who is trying to reach this page (in my case checking web.config for a particular username).

Wasn't actually very hard once I got the basic plumbing done but requires C# coding skills (not necessarily Visual Studio if you can live with some basic tools like Notepad++ and the CodePlex WSPBuilder commandline tool).

Let me know if you're up for some rough C# code and I'll dig it up from an old archive once I'm back at home from traveling later.